# Download Microsoft Office without logging to a Microsoft account

Tags: microsoft-office

I'm reinstalling a friend's PC, and now I have to install Microsoft Office 2016 Home & Student. My friend gave to me the card with the product key, the instructions say to go to https://www.office.com/setup however I can't download the installer without logging in a Microsoft Account. Of course I don't have my friend's credentials, I just want to download and install the software, he'll log into his account and then he'll activate the software.

So how do I download the Microsoft Office installer?

Comment: Scroll to bottom....https://office-home-and-student-2016.en.softonic.com/

Comment: @Moab: that link eventually takes you to buy a new Office licence on microsoft.com

Comment: What does the card actually license you to access? Most Microsoft licenses are tied to accounts now, so you'll need an account anyways to get it. Further, the education license is only authorized for specific limited purposes and Microsoft has a vested interest in validating that you meet those criteria.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm reinstalling a friend's PC, and now I have to install Microsoft Office 2016 Home & Student. My friend gave to me the card with the product key, the instructions say to go to https://www.office.com/setup however I can't download the installer without logging in a Microsoft Account.

If the product key is associated with your friend’s Microsoft Account then your friend will have to log into their account.

If the product key is unused you need to access your Microsoft Account, and associate the product key, with your Microsoft Account.

> So how do I download the Microsoft Office installer?

You will be unable to download the correct edition of Office, that will accept the product key your friend has, without claiming the product key and associating the key with a Microsoft Account.

**Once the key is claimed your friend can provide you a link to the product.**

Answer (score 1):

You can't install office 2016 Home & Student without logging to a Microsoft account.

For Office 2016 Home & Student, you must sign in the right [Microsoft account](https://account.microsoft.com/services/) portal and on the Service and subscriptions page, to download it. Then you will install it according to the wizard.

You can review this in the official article [Download and install or reinstall Office 2016 or Office 2013](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/download-and-install-or-reinstall-office-2016-or-office-2013-7c695b06-6d1a-4917-809c-98ce43f86479)